# Does (n%2==1) always convey that n is a odd number?

Tags: python-3.x

I had recently had a problem with (n%2==1).
The problem was to calculate the number of even and odd numbers in an array. When I tried the above mentioned condition in my code it resulted in a wrong answer. But when I changed it to (n%2==0) it was accepted. Can anyone help me on this?

The code in Python:

```
n = int(input())
ct = 0

a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
for i in a:
    if((i%2)==1):
        ct+=1

ct1 = n-ct
print(ct,ct1)
```

Comment: `i%2 = 0` when `i` is even.

Comment: We would have to see the test case when it fails. A number `x` is even if `x % 2 == 0`. Similarly a number `x` is odd if `x % 2 == 1`. However, I think this line is messing you up, look closely at what you are doing `ct1 = n-ct`.

Comment: Also if you want the number of odds you can just use `sum` as in: `odds = sum(1 for x in a if x % 2 == 1)`

Comment: @Error or `odds = sum( x%2 == 1 for x in a)` - because True == 1

Comment: @PatrickArtner I thought there was a better way to write it, but my brain had a lapse, thank you.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Why not `odds = sum(x%2 for x in a)`?

Comment: @mark Hehe - even better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, you are printing the output as

> > oddNumberCount evenNumberCount

But the problem wants you to print it as

> > evenNumberCount oddNumberCount

So when you switch it to n%2==0, i.e, check for even numbers, it gets accepted because that is the format the problem wants you to print the numbers in.